# How to cancel showing a page and show another page instead in Jquery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i'm building a mobile app with Jquery Mobile and i need to cancel showing a page and show another page instead, based in some rules.

I have the following code:

```
$('#login').live("pagebeforeshow", function() {
    /*-> Here i have some code where i decide 
    if i continue loading the page or load(changepage) another page instead.*/
});
```

Thanks in advice for helping me.
Should i better use "pagebeforecreate" instead of "pagebeforeshow" or what do you recommend?

Comment: why do you want to create a page when you dont even plan to use it? :-/

Comment: Because i need to check if the user is already logged in, and if it's not then i need to continue showing the "#login" page (because this is the first page). If the user is logged in then i need to show the #panel page.

Answer (score 0):

`.live()` is deprecated, use `.on()` instead:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", "#login", function(event){ 
   if(condition){
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      $.mobile.changePage("login.htm");
   }
});
```